# Python: getting type error

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I'm getting a type error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: '`tuple`' and '`float`'
```

I have this as code:

```
elif corner == "SW":
    return ((self.centerx)-(xcoord)),((self.centery) - (ycoord))
```

Why am I getting a type error for the subtraction sign?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] we can all compile and run.

Comment: hmmm `unsupported operand type(s) for -: '`tuple`' and '`float`'`. What's unclear? One operand is tuple, the other is float. `-` does not work used with tuple and float.

Comment: Wow, as a first time Python user, I should know why. Thanks for the constructive answer, dick

Answer (score 1):

While I concur with @Code-Apprentice, that your code example is not complete and thus makes it difficult to provide an answer...

I will make the following suggestions.

The error means that your code is trying to calculate the difference between a `tuple` and a `float` value.

```
((self.centerx)-(xcoord)),((self.centery) - (ycoord))
```

If you were to examine your variables:

```
self.centerx
xcoord
self.centery
ycoord
```

you would likely find that one OR more of them is a `tuple` and one or more them is a `float`.

A simple** way to examine them would be to insert a snippet of code like this, right before your line of sample code.

```
print(type(self.centerx),
      type(xcoord),
      type(self.centery),
      type(ycoord))
((self.centerx)-(xcoord)),((self.centery) - (coord))
```

You will probably see something like this:

```
<class 'tuple'> <class 'float'> <class 'tuple'> <class 'float'>
```

At that point, you would need to find a way to normalize your values so that you can perform the calculation you want to do. But that would be a separate question.

** NOTE: while using `type()` will work in many cases, for simple examination of Python objects, it may sometimes run into problems, in which case `isinstance()` is the correct solution.